# Visual Basic global rounding up function for other mathematical features

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working within Visual Basic console application.

I have created a number of mathematical features such as quadratic equation and prime factorisation.

However, my next task is to create a mathematical feature that you're able to enter and select the number of decimal places you wish to get your answers for the other mathematical features.

For example let's call this function decimalPoint:

You enter decimal point - you're asked how many decimal places you'd like your answers to. You chose 2.
You go back to the main menu and select quadratic equation, after inputting the coefficients then the output of the quadratic equation has to output in 2.d.p.

I'm able to ask the user for an input and just convert that into whatever d.p I need, but I don't know how to link it to other subs/functions.

So Far I have something along the lines:

```
Sub decimalPoint
dim Input As Integer
Console.WriteLine("Welcome")
Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of decimal place you wish to save to 1-5", 1-6) 'max 5dp.
input = Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

''Now I could do something like Console.WriteLine(Round(Convert.ToDecimal(input), 2)), but that's only based on whatever they input and not related to other functions/subs that I need it for. Any idea how I can link this to other subs?

notes:
It's a program with a menu.

**Update:** I got something along these lines now, but it's still not working.

```
Module Module1
    Public Property MyResult As ...
    Public Property MyDecimalInput As ...
    Sub QuadraticFunction()
    ....Calculations
    Console.WriteLine("Chose a decimal input: 1-5")
    If ... = ... Then
    Call decimalPoint()
    MyResult =  (....)
    End Sub
    Sub decimalPoint()
    If MyDecimalInput = ...
    Math.Round(MyResult) ...
    ...
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: The Input variable is of no use as a local variable, it needs to be a field of your class or module.  So you can use it in other methods.

Comment: That's true, but how would I be able to do that? I'm quite new to all of this.

Comment: If a variable is declared inside a method then it is local to that method.  What's the opposite of inside a method?

Comment: updated main question

Comment: Guess i'm stuck on passing contents of one variable from 1 sub to another

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but this is how I interpreted your question, but does this answer your question? If not let me know and I'll do my best to help :)

```
    'converts text in textbox to integer 
    Dim decimalPoint As Integer = Convert.ToInt64(addTB.Text)

    'stores newly rounded function into a number of user specified decimal places
    Dim answer As Double = Math.Round(13.17435, decimalPoint)

    'displays rounded answer
    MsgBox(answer)
```

Comment: Hmm no, not quite but thanks for trying. I'm actually making us of the vb console & not the .net. Also, I have to make a function to allow me to pick from 1-5 d.p.s and when I go onto a mathematical feature it will output the answer to that specific amount of d.p